# What is the exact difference between extrauser and useradd

Tags: yocto

In one recipe i can see the following but it is not creating any extra user or group, that i confirmed while inspecting rpm file.

```
inherit extrausers
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "\
        useradd -p '' example; \
        groupadd example; \
        "
```

So I added the following in the recipe which created a user and group for me.

```
inherit useradd
USERADD_PACKAGES = "${PN}"
GROUPADD_PARAM_${PN} = "--system example"
USERADD_PARAM_${PN} = "--system -M -d /var/lib/example -s /bin/false -g example example"
```

What is the exact difference between useradd and extrausers in yocto. Why extrausers cannot able to create user and group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**extrausers** add user/group at image level and cannot be tied to a specific recipe, and that's the role of **useradd** class, it can be used on a recipe.

Read the note [here](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/classes.html#extrausers-bbclass):

> Note
>
> The user and group operations added using the extrausers class are not
> tied to a specific recipe outside of the recipe for the image. Thus,
> the operations can be performed across the image as a whole. Use the
> useradd class to add user and group configuration to a specific
> recipe.

And here is the note for [useradd](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/classes.html#useradd-bbclass):

> The useradd* classes support the addition of users or groups for usage
> by the package on the target. For example, if you have packages that
> contain system services that should be run under their own user or
> group, you can use these classes to enable creation of the user or
> group.